# ArrayList<String> not being adding to object (JAVA)

Tags: java, arraylist

Programme class which contains a code and module(s)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Programme {

    private ArrayList<String> modules = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String ProgrammeCode;

    public Programme(String ProgrammeName) {
        this.ProgrammeCode = ProgrammeName;
        if (modules.size() > 0) {
            modules.clear(); //clear if something in modules
        }
    }

    public Programme(String programmeCode, ArrayList<String> moduleList) {
        this.ProgrammeCode = programmeCode;
        modules = moduleList;
    }

    public void addModule(String name) {
        if (name != null && !name.equals("")) {
            modules.add(name);
        }
    }

    public String getProgrammeCode() {
        return ProgrammeCode;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getModules() {
        return modules;
    }

    public int getModuleCount() {
        return modules.size();
    }
}
```

This is in the class that reads csv files and stores them into type Programme, but i have a problem adding the strings into modules.

```
public ArrayList<Programme> loadProgrammes() {
    ArrayList<String> modules = new ArrayList<String>(); //.... modules are being read from
    //a csv file and have done multiple tests and its working correctly   
    modules.add(".....");

    //PROBLEM HERE     
    programmes.add(new Programme(programmeStrings.get(i).get(0), modules));
    //this displays as i want it to e.g. when added:3:[MA4102, CS4092, CS4162] 
    System.out.print("when added:" + programmes.get(i).getModuleCount() + ":" + modules);

    //where as this doesn't work e.g.  //Finished list:3 //LM023 0 []
    //LM051 0 [] //LM110 0 [] 
    System.out.println("\nFinished list:" + programmes.size());
    for (int t = 0; t < programmes.size(); t++) {
        System.out.println(programmes.get(t).getProgrammeCode() + " " + programmes.get(t).getModuleCount() + " "
                + programmes.get(t).getModules());
    }

    return programmes;
}
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong. Why isn't it adding the modules to the programme object

Comment: This is extremely difficult to read due to the bad formatting.  Please format your code in a readable way.

Comment: Use a debugger, it will tell you EXACTLY where and what is wrong.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information.  But it could be a problem that `new Programme(programmeStrings.get(i).get(0), modules)` is setting the `Programme`'s `modules` to be the same *reference* as `modules`, which means that any time something is added to the `modules` variable, it will affect the `Programme` also, and vice versa.  You may need your second `Programme` constructor to make a copy of the `ArrayList`.

Comment: You need to show the relevant code of where all these variables originate from. We don't know what any of them mean.

Comment: in this line of code: `programmes.add(new Programme(programmeStrings.get(i).get(0), modules));` where do you initialize `programmeStrings` which i assume is a `List`?

Comment: programmeString is from reading the csv file in, programmeStrings.get(i).get(0) is the the programmeCode e.g. LM110

Comment: Could you post full code? I think that would be easier for every one :)